# How to call a script from webpage served by apache

Tags: php, python, perl, escaping, html

I am trying to create a webpage form that when submitted, it would call a filebot script (or any program in Unix with a large list of parameters".  When I run this command from the Unix prompt, it runs just fine.  WOuld love to create a webpage that I can click on "submit" to run this program.

```
/usr/bin/filebot -script fn:amc "/home/user/jDownloads/Extracted/" --output "/home/user/Videos" --log-file amc.log --action copy -non-strict --def clean=y "seriesFormat=TV/{n} {'S'+s}/{n} {sxe} - {t}" "animeFormat=Cartoons/{n} {sxe - {t}" "movieFormat=Movies/{n} {y}/{sxe}" musicFormat=Music/{n}/{fn}"
```

I am open to using a `perl`, `python`, or `php script` as handler to the form submission.

Due to the large number of special characters, I am having a hard time getting the command properly "escaped" in any of the mentioned scripting languages.

Would be great if someone can help out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there should be no need to escape any characters if you wrap the string in triple quotes.

```
cmd = """/usr/bin/filebot -script fn:amc "/home/u... etc"""
```

And then you can call it using the subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html